# What difference method does the default ConvectionTerm take?

Tags: fipy

I want to know which difference method the default ConvectionTerm uses in fipy, upwind difference or central difference or else？
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`ConvectionTerm` is an alias for [`PowerLawConvectionTerm`](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/fipy/generated/fipy.terms.html#module-fipy.terms.powerLawConvectionTerm). The power law scheme is described [here](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/documentation/numerical/scheme.html#sec-numericalschemes).